# Can't access inherited method in test environment Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, integration-testing, minitest

I am trying to write a test to check a user flow in my application. For that, I need to test a method called `is_apple` that is in  `AppleController`, AppleController is inherited from `FruitsController`. I have a method in FruitsController called `taste` which can be used inside `AppleController's is_apple` method. The output is the same as expected in the Development and Production environment. But In the Test environment, The method from the FruitsController is undefined in AppleController. I am new to rails testing, I don't know what is potentially causing this issue in my application's test environment.

test_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    puts "starting a test"
    post "v1/is_apple", params: {colour: 'red', taste: 'sweet'} 
  end
end
```

apple_controller.rb

```
module V1
  class AppleController < FruitsController
    def is_apple
      return true if taste and params[:colour].eql?('red')
    end
  end
end
```

fruits_controller.rb

```
module V1
  class FruitsController < ActionController::API
    def taste
      # assume
      return true
    end
  end
end
```

I am using minitest '5.10.3' and rails 6. When I run rails test, am getting undefined_method 'taste' in AppleController. Is there any mistakes in my code? , If yes, How can I achieve the behaviour I wanted. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, have you tried putting your request inside of a test case instead of the setup? Something like:
 
test "is apple" do
   post "v1/is_apple", params: {colour: 'red', taste: 'sweet'}
end

Comment: No, I haven't tried it yet. will check that.